# Naming a method which does several actions

Tags: c++, coding-style

I know that one method should be responsible for one action (or so I've been told) but let's it can't be avoided (or workaround is impractical). Imagine that a game of snake is being developed and it has to have two methods: one which simply moves snake forward and one which increments the length of the snake by one and moves it. First method could just be named **move()**, but how about the second one? Simpliest solution is to use *and*, but is it a good practice? For example: **incrementAndMove()**. What are the alternatives?

Comment: Why not? Sounds fine to me.

Comment: You can create one increment() one move() and one incrementAndMove(), that way each is responsible for something unique.

Comment: If the motions are distinct (decoupled) then it seems there should be 2 methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would choose the name `GrowAndMove`, but semantically it is the same as what you propose. Still implement this method to call two separate methods - `Grow` and `Move` to keep each method responsible for a single aspect of the changes happening during a single step.